# Assigning PFUser attribute to UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am retrieving the `currentUser()` from Parse and attempting to set its `first_name` attribute to a UILabel.

I downcast the value to a String and print out its `dynamicType` to make sure it succeeds.

However when I try to assign the value to `username.text`, it throws a fatal error.

Code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let firstname = PFUser.currentUser()?.valueForKey("first_name") as? String {
        print(firstname.dynamicType)
        print(firstname)
        username.text = firstname
    } else {
        print("Fail")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
String
Jonnyboy
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Clearly I am missing something trivial. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to declare username as non-optional? For example, could you change your declaration to: `@IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if let firstname = PFUser.currentUser()?.valueForKey("first_name") as? String {
        print(firstname.dynamicType)
        print(firstname)
        username.text = firstname!
    } else 
    {
        print("Fail")
    }
```

Comment: There shouldn't need to be a `!` in `"\(firstname!" right? Since the cast is for `String` and not an optional `String?`

Comment: for some reason i think his code kept returning an optional string so it doesn't hurt to cast it again @Russell